# find divisble for a number from x to y

Tags: java, module

currently im trying to find the divisibility for a number the user inputs and the number should be divisible from x to y

> example: 2520 is divisible by all numbers from 1-10.

so here is what i done so far, so clearly i coded it in a bad way, can anyone do better?

```
public static void main (String[] args){
    Scanner kb = new Scanner(System.in);
    int temp = 0,x,y,num;
    System.out.println("enter the number to check for");
    num = kb.nextInt();
    System.out.println("enter the starting number");
    x = kb.nextInt();
    System.out.println("enter the ending number");
    y=kb.nextInt();

    while(x >= y){
        System.out.println("starting num must be less then the ending num,re-enter the starting num.");
        x = kb.nextInt();
        System.out.println(" now enter the ending number, must be greater then the starting num");
        y=kb.nextInt();
    }
    while ( num % x == 0 && x < y){
        x++;
    }
    if ( x == y){
        System.out.println("the number "+ num + " is divisble by this range.");
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean "evenly divisible from x to y"?

Comment: Do you mean divisible by every number in the given range?

Comment: just removed it to be more clear, i simply mean that all numbers should be divisble ( remainder should be 0 )

Comment: Still not clear. Try giving an example.

Comment: yes @gla3dr thats what i mean

Comment: `a=10`, then you want `2` and `5`, the factorials as answers? Or do you want `2` because of the possible outcomes? (Within the specified ranges that is.)

Comment: @Emz heres an example : 2520 is divisible from all numbers from 1-10.

Comment: I think OP wants the following: Input: `n, a, b`; Output: `true` (if `n` is divisible by `a,a+1,...,b`) or `false` (otherwise).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Write it as a helper method:

```
public static boolean isDivisibleByAll(int dividend, int fromDivisor, int toDivisor) {
    for (int divisor = fromDivisor; divisor <= toDivisor; divisor++)
        if (dividend % divisor != 0)
            return false;
    return true;
}
```

Comment: amazing highly efficient.

Answer (score 0):

Some things to consider:

- It would be more user-friendly if you accepted the integers in either order.  If the first is larger than the second, just go from the second to the first.  So, something like:

  ```
  int swapInt;
  if (x > y)
  {
      swapInt = x;
      x = y;
      y = swapInt;
  }
  ```
- It would be more user-friendly if you accepted the same integer for the start and end.  The user might want to just check one number.  (How would you change your code to do this?)
- It looks like you accept any integers, including zero and negative integers.  Will your program still work?  If not, what would you have to change?

Comment: for the zeros and negative numbers ill make a case for that, my issue would be if the person choose the first number as the same number, i like the idea of swapping the numbers though.